# What is the product of CO + 2H2 under normal pressure?

Tags: physical-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Under the pressure of $\pu{340 atm}$

$$\ce{CO + 2H2 <=> CH3OH}$$

But what is its product during normal pressure of $\pu{1 atm}$? I think it would be a single displacement reaction

$$\ce{CO + 2H2 <=> CH4 + O2}$$

but I'm not sure. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is all very much dependent on the catalyst and temperature that you use. At 340 atm it is also easily possible to get CH4 out of the reaction. The CO, H2 mixture is called *syngas* and the type of reaction you are looking at is the [Fischer-Tropsch process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fischer%E2%80%93Tropsch_process). You might want to look into that!

Comment: @Michiel why don't you post an answer? Answer questions in  comments is not a good practice! We will stay in beta forever!:-)

Comment: @GM I don't consider what I wrote an answer t all. It is merely a bit of 'pointing in the right direction'. I didn't have the time to do the search myself, hence the comment. (with success because the OP found the reaction himself)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot  Michiel I got the answer in the Fischer-Tropsch process. During normal atmospheric pressure the following reaction occurs :

$$\ce{CO + 3H2 <=> CH4 + H2O}$$

Also could someone tell me the type of reaction this is? I think it is partially a displacement reaction for $\ce{O}$ is displaced by $\ce{H}$ and gives $\ce{CH4}$, but then $\ce{O}$ is left out and reacts with the remaining two hydrogen and gives $\ce{H2O}$.

Comment: Please post your second question as a new question. Otherwise it will not get any attention and it is not useful for the community.